# Get the value of a dropdown attribute of an associated product

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, grouped-products, associate-products

I'm trying to display the (non empty) attribute values of all associated products in a grouped product.

My main issue are the dropdown attributes

I can display the manufacturer value but not the color one. Any other custom attribute is not visible either.

I have tried to solve it using this solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8754579/is-it-possible-to-show-custom-attributes-of-associated-products-under-a-grouped

I have also tried loading a specific associated product by Sku without success.

Comment: is flat tables active?

Comment: Yes, they are active.

Comment: show your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deactive the flat tables config

Or
let it be active but set the attribute value "use in product listing" to yes (reindex data after that)